# Any benefit to call Any() over an IEnumerable before enumerating it?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any benefit of calling .Any() on an enumeration right before enumerating it ? For example (granted that list is an IEnumerable):

```
if(list != null && list.Any()) 
{
    foreach(var item in list) 
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I suspect that it has none, but I'd rather be sure.

Comment: @DavidL That assumes that it implements `ICollection` and not just `IEnumerable`

Comment: What benefit would you be expecting?  A performance benefit?

Comment: It actually has a downside: `list` gets enumerated twice. Which you should avoid for plain `IEnumerable<T>`s, since not all of them support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real benefit, but possible downside to calling `Any` here as you could be enumerating twice.

A null check should be enough. The foreach will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: Actually, if I recall correctly, .Any() just makes one call to .MoveNext() once, so yes it will be enumerated, but not on the whole enumeration.

Comment: @SebastienF it depends on the provider. So it is a potential downside.

Comment: @manojlds, what do you mean by - it depends on the provider? Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

No not really. If the list is empty your foreach loop will simply not iterate.

```
if(list != null) 
{
    foreach(var item in list) 
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for unneeded and false comparison of Any with Count() > 0, especially for IEnumerable. Count() will always have to enumerate all the elements. Any need not.

Comment: sad that I can't -1 you for being unable to read. Do you see brackets behind me `Count` property?

Comment: Does IEnumerable have Count property?

Answer (score 0):

No, no real benefit.

If the list is not null, but empty, foreach will be fine (i.e. it will not throw an exception and it won't enumerate over an empty list).
Doing the null check should be enough.